# How to store data after doing a large pull from database? PHP

Tags: php

I am generating pages using PHP, and displaying information pulled from a database.

Suppose I have a box that can show a maximum of 5 items, but my sql query has returned 30 items. What is an effective way to store the other 25 items and access them later?

Comment: Use `LIMIT` in your queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the records in the $_SESSION variable after the first query and write your code to search the returned values from this session variable.

Write example:

```
$_SESSION['data'][0]['field1'] = 'value of first field of the first record';
$_SESSION['data'][0]['field2'] = 'value of second field of the first record';
$_SESSION['data'][1]['field1'] = 'value of first field of the second record';
```

Read example:

```
echo 'Record 1, Field 1: ' . $_SESSION['data'][0]['field1'];
echo 'Record 1, Field 2: ' . $_SESSION['data'][0]['field2'];
echo 'Record 2, Field 1: ' . $_SESSION['data'][1]['field1'];
```

Alternatively you can store this information in a javascript variable and perform the exibition of data without performing get or post, using only client-side code after the first query.

Comment: Would it be better to store it with Javascript or to use ajax to update the view?

Comment: If you store the data in javascript you don't need do an http request (ajax) to retrieve the information. If you store in the session, you will need get the values using ajax. 
I think do not exist the 'best' way for this answer without an analisys of you data and server. All depends of type of information,  size of information and server resources.